# Can user still log on if local DC (which is also the DNS & DHCP) fails?

Tags: domain-controller

I have only 1 domain with 3 DCs (all of them are GC, DNS, DHCP).  The DCs are located at 3 different sites, A, B, C. If site B DC fails, can a user at site B log in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, under specific circumstances:

1. If they can connect directly to another site's domain controllers, they can still log in despite their own site's domain controllers being down (assuming they have alternate DNS to find a domain controller)
2. If their credentials are cached on the local machine, they can log in despite potentially no domain controllers at all being available.

But if a node doesn't have DHCP, then even with a successful login the user probably won't be able to do much.

Comment: Also, without dhcp, the client machine may not have a valid IP address to connect to the network. And dependent on your client machine's DNS configuration, they may not have access to a DNS server in order to access anything in local or remote sites.